# Highchart combination chart with stacked column

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to achieve a combination chart with column and stacked chart for summary.

Exactly like the one they have it in the demo section. however, i want to display a stacked column chart instead of pie in this example. 
   [Highcart combination chart example demo](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types)

```
[this is not a link]https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/
```

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding second axes and stacked column series linked to them. Series should have null points to create an offset on the right side. Check the example posted below.

Code:

```js
var defaultColumnSeries = {
  type: 'column',
  stacking: 'normal',
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
      fontSize: '9px'
    }
  },
  showInLegend: false,
  groupPadding: 0.1,
  yAxis: 1,
  xAxis: 1
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Combination chart'
  },
  xAxis: [{
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
  }, {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums'],
    visible: false
  }],
  yAxis: [{

  }, {
    top: 30,
    height: 150,
    visible: false,
    stackLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
      }
    }
  }],
  labels: {
    items: [{
      html: 'Total fruit consumption',
      style: {
        left: '20px',
        top: '-20px',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
      }
    }]
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'John',
    data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
  }, {
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Average',
    data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
    marker: {
      lineWidth: 2,
      lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
      fillColor: 'white'
    }
  }, Highcharts.merge(defaultColumnSeries, {
   data: [4, 3, 2, 6, 3, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
  }), Highcharts.merge(defaultColumnSeries, {
   data: [1, 4, 7, 3, 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
  }), Highcharts.merge(defaultColumnSeries, {
   data: [5, 2, 1, 3, 4, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
  })]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jy02qsru/1/