# How to combine column and staked bar highchart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, frontend

I have a question about combining column and staked bar for react highchart,
it is similar to the answer of this link:
[Highchart combination chart with stacked column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267093/highchart-combination-chart-with-stacked-column)

but I want to change the above column to stacked bar which is horizontal.
When I change the defaultColumnSeries to

```
var defaultColumnSeries = {
  type: 'bar',
  stacking: 'normal',
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
      fontSize: '9px'
    }
  },
  showInLegend: false,
  groupPadding: 0.1,
  yAxis: 1,
  xAxis: 1
}
```

then all the columns become horizontal also which is not what I want.
I want to keep the below columns vertical and the above stacked bar horizontal.
What should I do to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bar` series type enables `chart.inverted` option, which makes it impossible to use `column` and `bar` series types on the same chart. As a solution, you can create another chart and place it on top of the other.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k3z5opvr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted

**Github issue:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13363

Comment: thanks @ppotaczek, this is exactly what i want to achieve